# gulp build returns unclosed string error

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm running gulp v3.9.1 and Nodejs v8.11.1. I built out my MobileMenu.js file like below:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class MobileMenu {
    constructor() {
        this.siteHeader = $(".site-header");
        this.menuIcon = $(".site-header__menu-icon"); // selects the menu div that we are clicking
        this.menuContent = $(".site-header__menu-content"); //selects the hidden div that we want to display when it's clicked
        this.events();
    } 

    events() {
        this.menuIcon.click(this.toggleTheMenu.bind(this)); //adding .bind allows this to target anything inside the () within bind
    }

    toggleTheMenu() {
        this.menuContent.toggleClass("site-header__menu-content--is-visible");//adds new class to the selected menuContent
        this.siteHeader.toggleClass("site-header--is-expanded");
        this.menuIcon.toggleClass("site-header__menu-icon--close-x");
    }

}

export default MobileMenu;
```

Menu works fine on localhost. I build out a gulp build task and run `$ gulp build` and get the following error:

> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ Error: C:\Users\rlwel\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Hexpose\hexpose-corporate-site\assets\styles\styles-bdf74771e1.css:11344:71:
>   Unclosed string  11342 |
>   this.menuContent.toggleClass("site-header__menu-content--is-visible");
>   //adds new class to the selected menuContent   11343 |
>   this.siteHeader.toggleClass("site-header--is-expanded");
>
> > 11344 |             this.menuIcon.toggleClass("site-header__menu-icon--close-x");
> >             |                                                                       ^

The most important part is "unclosed string" obviously, and I read somewhere that this could be a missing string literal error, but I'm not quite sure how to fix it, and I'm a little new to gulp.

Is there something within this file that I need to close?

Comment: Could you post your gulpfile? Or at least the task(s) you are trying to run here?